# SELECT statement in ELSE part?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I believe SELECT statement in ELSE is also possible, right?

I have this query:

```
CASE ORDER1
        WHEN NULL
            THEN ''
        ELSE (
                SELECT P.VENDOR_ID
                FROM ORDERS1${RGCM_CAMP_LOGIC_SUFFIX} P
                LEFT JOIN ORDERS2${RGCM_CAMP_LOGIC_SUFFIX} O
                    ON P.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
                WHERE P.ORDER_DATE = O.ORDER1
                )
        END AS VENDOR_ID1
```

I am pretty sure, subquery returns only 1 row still i am getting error :
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

I am checking if there is any ORDER1 then its VENDOR_ID should be selected and be known as VENDOR_ID1.

Where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's returning only 1 result? Try running it sepparately and see the results.

Comment: Run that query as a standalone query and check if it really always returns only one row.

Comment: Change the `SELECT P.VENDOR_ID` with `SELECT COUNT(*)` and look for the result(s) containing two (or more) rows.

Comment: Yes i made some tweaking now, that error is not showing up anymore, but the error is :
CASE WHEN ORDER1 NULL THEN '' ELSE (SELECT P.VENDOR_ID FROM ORDERS16F50TQDWsb P LEFT JOIN ORDERS26F50TQDWsb O ON P.CUSTOMER_ID=O.CUSTOMER_ID WHERE P.ORDER_DATE=O.ORDER1 AND P.CUSTOMER_ID=O.CUSTOMER_ID) END AS VENDOR_ID1,
                    *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

I am just skeptical it DATE datatypes can be compared directly with '=' ? Or do i need to use some func like TO_CHAR or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your re-write of the case expression is giving that ORA error because you forgot the IS NULL

CASE WHEN ORDER1 **IS** NULL

BUT:
I wouldn't recommend using a correlated subquery in the select clause - seems a very inefficient method - even if it inside a case expression.

There isn't enough of your overall query here to know exactly what to propose, but you should move that logic into a join, something like this

```
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
    , ORDER_DATE
    , VENDOR_ID
FROM ORDERS16F50TQDWsb
) P ON O.CUSTOMER_ID = P.CUSTOMER_ID
AND O.ORDER1 = P.ORDER_DATE
```

Note, you MIGHT have to use GROUP BY here so that you don't get more rows than expected, but if you do need to do this then you may also have to take the MAX(ORDER_DATE) [or MIN()] as appropriate. Only with much more detail of your overall query could I be more exact then this.

Once you sort out how you are collecting that information then your case expression would be much simpler:

```
CASE WHEN ORDER1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE P.VENDOR_ID END AS VENDOR_ID1,
```

and, you would need to ensure that the date type of VENDOR_ID1 is a string, it it isn't then you have to use to_char(VENDOR_ID1) so it is compatible with that empty string.

Lastly, you most certainly can compare dates using the equal operator; BUT the data might not be equal, e.g. there may be a few seconds or minutes difference. It might be necessary to truncate the dates to remove that issue, e.g.

TRUNC(O.ORDER1) = TRUNC(P.ORDER_DATE)

but only do this is really needed otherwise you are wasting effort with those TRUNC() functions.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 - SELECT MAX(P.VENDOR_ID)  or
 - SELECT TOP 1 P.VENDOR_ID
```

Comment: TOP is also in Oracle? I thought is MS-SQL specific